# SharePoint 2010 Workflow Deployemnet from DEV to UAT

Tags: 2010, workflow, content-type, deployment

I have Sharepoint 2010 DEV and UAT sites. I have made some changes in  DEV workflow and I want to deploy the changed workflow to UAT site.
I have created the workflow template and saved .wsp file to UAT solutions gallery and activated it.
But the problem is in Content types related to the workflow. They are not updated with DEV changes.
Please let me know how to handle content types that need to be deployed with changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can include the content types in the .wsp solution file for automatic deployment.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479975(v=office.14).aspx for a reference

You can also do/run whatever you did to create the content type on DEV on UAT as part of the deployment. Sometimes it makes more sense to do simple things manually rather than making it all part of the .wsp file.